# Simulation of real world scenario on simulink/simscape

Tags: matlab, simulation, simulink, simscape

I'm planning on simulating a real world scenario in Matlab. I have an experimental setup inside a closed environment in which the humidity is controlled predominantly. I'm studying the effects of humidity on the machine and see if the output of the machine itself along with the raw material fed into the machine depends on the varying levels of humidity. Is it possible to mimic the same environment in Simulink/Simscape without any test dataset solely depending on the physical equations of the physical parameters and the machine and materials involved? As an example, i can state the working of a machine to extrude plastic resins in a closed environment where the humidity is kept constant at different levels and the efficiency of the extruder at different levels of humidity is calculated based on the experiments. Can i repeat the same in simulink/simscape by setting up the same model? My aim would be to compare the real world scenario with the matlab model. I would be grateful to get some expert opinions/help/answers inside the stack**overflow** community. Thank you!

Comment: The physical modelling of humidity or deformable hard matter might not be included in simulink yet. Have you already contacted Mathworks and asked for it?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/simscape/physical-modeling.html i was of the impression that this is the very basic fundamental of simscape

Comment: Yes, you can probably model this in Simscape, but it will take a lot of thought on your part. For one, there is no Simscape domain ready-made for plastic extrusion models, much less one that can factor in the effects of humidity... You would probably need to create a custom domain with custom components based on equations that you'll... have to dig up from somewhere... Maybe you can do it if you know the physics of plastic extrusion well... but my guess is... it would be a challenge, probably?